# Bootstrap dropdown nav bar misbehaving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to get bootstrap drop down nav bar to work. Nav bar is loading but the drop down functionality is not working. I have followed the following example

When I open the html file and check the js console I do see the following error"Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery  bootstrap.min.js:6:37"

I have not added any jQuery to my code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#skills">Skills<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projects<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#schools">Schools</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Contact Me<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is working fine.

Comment: Here the fiddle work's fine too, remember to include jquery before boostrap.

Comment: are you including jquery before bootstrap on the page that isn't working?

Comment: it's working. maybe you need to clear the browser cache

Comment: need to add jquery-2.1.1.min.js

Comment: actually Im not an expert on this. I have copied exactly the example from the js fiddle that works. But when I add to html file i get the jquery error.

Comment: I am clicking it. But no drop down is coming.

Comment: @Matt, you also need to load jQuery lib, as Minar and Michael suggested. The fiddle has `jquery-1.11.3.js` loaded.

Comment: how do I add the jquery ?

Comment: Add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>`. Would be nice to look for a newer version though. 1.11.3 is hella old. This is just an example.

Comment: Thanks so much, was so confused about this. Thanks again, I really appreciate all the help. as doutriforce as suggested adding <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script> fixed my issue.

Comment: @Matt, no problem. Don't forget to look for a newer js version though. I don't know what you're using it for, maybe it would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"   integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

before the Bootstrap JS.

Comment: I think you mean _before_.

Comment: No probs, dude.